# How to create a search box in with a simple text field and a submit button in flask?

Tags: python, ajax, jquery, flask

On pressing submit the form should pass the value to the server. But I am getting this 500 internal server error. here's my views.py code :-

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template,request
import feedparser
import json
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def search():

    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/searchRSS',methods=['POST'])
def search_results():
    feed = feedparser.parse("http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&gl=in&q="+request.form['query']+"&um=1&output=rss" )
    posts = []
    for i in range(0,len(feed['entries'])):
        posts.append({
            'date': feed['entries'][i].title,
            'title': feed['entries'][i].updated,
            'description': feed['entries'][i].description

        })
    return json.dumps(posts, separators=(',', ':'))
```

and here's the index.html :-

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload=function (){
    $("#searcher").submit(function(ev) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */

        ev.preventDefault();



        $.post("/searchRSS", $("#searcher").serialize(),function(o)    {document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=o;});
})};
</script>
<form id="searcher" method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" id="query" name="query" required/>
<input type="submit" value="Get Feed"/>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: have you turned on debug mode to may be see the exact error ? app.debug = True

Comment: yeah i have, but  i dont know how to use it

Comment: if you have debug on, can you post the entire error stacktrace ?

Comment: POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/searchRSS 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) jquery.js:9597

Comment: @codegeek i am not getting any tracebacks actually
its like
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
can you please tell me how should i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chardet 2.1.3 does not appear to have been ported to Python 3.  You can read the author's case study on porting chardet [here](http://www.diveinto.org/python3/case-study-porting-chardet-to-python-3.html).  If you look the source code for the PyPi distro, it differs from the Python 3 port in the case study.

I was able to find a fork of chardet on GitHub that was ported to Python 3 here: https://github.com/byroot/chardet.  You may wish to test it with that fork and see if it resolves the issue.

Edit:
You should be able to use pip to install: `pip install https://github.com/byroot/chardet/zipball/master`  You may want to remove the current chardet first or test it in its own virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks. I removed python 3 and installed python 2.7 and i am able to import chardet now. But I am still getting this 500 internal server problem. plse help me out to solve it